# Can one YN600EX-RT II act as a transmitter only for another YN600EX-RT II?

Tags: flash, yongnuo, canon-5d-mark-iv

Can a Yongnuo flash YN600EX-RT II mounted on a Canon 5D Mark iv (or any canon camera for that matter), trigger another YN600EX-RT II mounted on another tripod, without triggering its own flash ? 
(need only the tripod mounted flash to get triggered. This is for a particular situation, and i don't want to spend money on a stand-alone transmitter only)

Can someone who has 2 of these YN600EX-RT II please check and confirm, before i make the purchase ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  Page 24 of the user manual describes how to control whether the master flash fires:

[image: yn600EX-RT II manual page 24]

So, basically:

1. Press the MENU2 soft button (4th below screen)
2. Press the flash on/off soft button (1st below screen) to cycle between turning the master unit ON or OFF, checking whether the icon on the main LCD has rays coming out of the flash head or not.

Comment: Hey Inkista, thanks a ton for your detailed answer.

Comment: @sohailahmad. You're welcome! Consider [accepting](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) or (when you have enough rep) upvoting an answer instead of thanking. :)  [The tour](https://photo.stackexchange.com/tour) will explain.